# Awesomium and it's framework. I keep getting a link error, but I copied the code verbatim. Why?

Tags: html, c++, awesomium

I honestly don't know what to put here.  I followed the tutorials at the Awesomium wiki and when I go to run the app I get an error Error:

```
1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   c:\Users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\AuctionExcell\AuctionExcell\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) AuctionExcell
```

I looked it up and people who got the same error had forgotten to put a main, but the main.cc has a main.  It's a really complicated one with a bunch of parameters, but it's there.  I tried putting just `int main() {` but it gave me the same error.  I'm not sure what the problem is.  I put the html in hoping it would render, but it didn't.  I am still on the "Hello world!" part.  It's frustrating, since I don't know what this means per se.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that all the required libraries are properly linked? It seems like a linking error -- the linker cannot find a library that you are referring to.

Comment: read error message, linker is looking for `_main` - with underscore

Comment: I copied over all the libraries it wanted.  It worked fine when I ran it before, but I might be missing some headers.  I'll check my old main.

Comment: @Lashane I'll try changing it. EDIT: I get the same error changing the weird main they gave me to _main

Comment: @Zackeezy libraries have nothing to do with headers.  you need to fix your linking, not compiling.  Link errors are not fixed with changes to source code.  They're changed by changing flags to your linker.

Comment: I added all the dll's it told me to, but for some reason it says I'm still missing something, I guess. E: How do I fix the flags, then?

Comment: Awesomium? Rather bold name for HTML UI from team of people who can't even make their front page look normal :)

Comment: @SergeyA It looks really cool in how it's supposed to work, though.  I'm excited to get past this stupid linking error and get to some actual coding in their syntax. (: